# Не понимаю как работать с медиазапросами

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. У меня структура постов: 4 маленьких и 2 больших, а затем 4 маленьких, 1 большой и 2 маленьких. Дело в том, что я не знаю что и на каких разрешениях экрана писать в медиа-запросы. Я не понимаю что мне нужно уменьшить или увеличить.

На разрешении с 974 до 730 вёрстка ломается. Шаблон верстаю сам для себя. К нему не прилагалось как и что должно выглядеть на 768, 480 и 320.

**До 768** у меня не получается, чтобы стояло 4 маленьких потом 2 больших, а затем 4 маленьких, 1 большой и 2 маленьких.

[Мой кривой код](https://jsfiddle.net/1gj2uyak/1/)

```css
.news {
  max-width: 980px;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.postSmall {
  flex-basis: 210px;
  height: 266px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 17px;
}
.postBig {
  flex-basis: 455px;
  height: 266px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 17px;
}
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {}
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {}
/* Small Devices, Tablets */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {}
/* Medium Devices, Desktops */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<section class="news">
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postBig"></div>
  <div class="postBig"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postBig"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
</section>
```

А с 768 вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите что делать? Вот сама проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Для начала давайте разберемся с использованием медиа-выражений. В зависимости от того, используете вы `(max-width: --px)` или `(min-width: --px)` получается разная направленность применяемых свойств.

### `(max-width: --px)`:

[image: max-width]

К примеру, код `@media (max-width: 766px) { ... }` применяется при ширине вьюпорта **от** 0 пикселей **до** 766 пикселей, что соответствует диапазону *3* на картинке. Т. о. вы задаёте *конечную границу* применения ваших свойств.

---

### `(min-width: --px)`:

[image: min-width]

При использовании `(min-width: --px)` всё происходит наоборот. Например, код `@media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }` будет применять диапазон *4* — **от** 1024 пикселей **до** бесконечности.

---

Чтобы делать такие резиновые раскладки я рекомендую использовать функцию `calc()`. У вас есть внешние отступы 17 пикселей, а значит можно для маленьких блоков задать `calc(25% - 34px)`, а для больших `calc(100% - 34px)`.

Ваша проблема начинается в диапазоне от 1010 пикселей и ниже, значит для этого участка можно написать следующий код:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1010px) {
  .postSmall {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 34px);
  }
  .postBig {
    flex-basis: calc(100% - 34px);
  }
}
```

```css
.news {
  max-width: 980px;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.postSmall {
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 34px);
  height: 266px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 17px;
}
.postBig {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 34px);
  height: 266px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 17px;
}
/* решение проблемы на определенном участке */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1010px) {
  .postSmall {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 34px);
  }
  .postBig {
    flex-basis: calc(100% - 34px);
  }
}
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {}
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {}
/* Small Devices, Tablets */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {}
/* Medium Devices, Desktops */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<section class="news">
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postBig"></div>
  <div class="postBig"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postBig"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.news{
 max-width: 980px;
 min-height: 500px;
 background-color: gray;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}

.postSmall{
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 266px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 17px solid #ff00ff;
}

.postBig{
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 266px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 17px solid #ff00ff;
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<section class="news">
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postBig"></div>
  <div class="postBig"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postBig"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
  <div class="postSmall"></div>
</section>
```